# how to use flags attribute with class inherit from enumeration

Tags: c#, oop, enums, domain-driven-design

How to implement multiple selections in a class which inherit from `Enumeration` With restrictions ?

If I have five schedule types:

- Fixed schedule
- Rotated schedule
- FullTime schedule
- PartTime schedule
- Flexible schedule

The first two options are versus `(Fixed vs Rotated)` and the second Two options `(FullTime  vs PartTime)` are versus, I mean the schedule can't be `fixed` and `rotated` at the same time or `fulltime and parttime` at the same time. but It may be `Fixed and FullTime` for example.

---

Fixed work schedules which consists of the same number of hours and days worked per week and tend to stay consistent once the number of hours and days have been agreed upon by both the employer and the worker.

Flexible work schedules in which employees and employers work together to determine the number of hours and days of the week they are able to commit to. 
Full time work schedule which often require a commitment of 37 - 40 hours per week. Because of the long hours, careers with full time schedules are eligible for work benefits. These benefits can include leave, vacation and sickness, health insurance, and different retirement plan options.

Part time work schedule which is any schedule less than full time employment.

Rotating work schedule which cycle employees through day or week, swing, and night shifts. This cycle helps to distribute different shifts between all employees so that no one is stuck with just the less desirable hours.

So I did the following:

```
public class Schedule
{
    public Schedule()
    {

    }

    private ICollection<ScheduleDetail> _assignedWeeks;
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int WorkingGroupId { get; set; }
    public ScheduleType ScheduleType { get; set; }
    public bool IsFixed { get; }
    public bool IsFlexible { get; }
    public bool IsFullTime { get; }
    public ICollection<ScheduleDetail> AssignedWeeks { get => _assignedWeeks; set => _assignedWeeks = value; }
}
```

---

```
public abstract class ScheduleType : Enumeration
    {
        protected ScheduleType(int value, string displayName) : base(value, displayName)
        {
        }
        public static readonly ScheduleType Fixed
       = new FixedType();
        public static readonly ScheduleType Flexible
            = new FlexibleType();
        public static readonly ScheduleType FullTime
            = new FullTimeType();
        public static readonly ScheduleType PartTime
           = new PartTimeType();
        public static readonly ScheduleType Rotated
           = new RotatedType();



        private class FixedType : ScheduleType
        {
            public FixedType() : base(1, "Fixed Work Schedule")
            {
            }
        }

        private class FlexibleType : ScheduleType
        {
            public FlexibleType() : base(2, "Flexible Work Schedule")
            {
            }
        }

        private class FullTimeType : ScheduleType
        {
            public FullTimeType() : base(3, "Full Time Work Schedule")
            {
            }
        }

        private class PartTimeType : ScheduleType
        {
            public PartTimeType() : base(4, "Part Time Work Schedule")
            {
            }
        }
        private class RotatedType : ScheduleType
        {
            public RotatedType() : base(5, "Rotated Work Schedule")
            {
            }
        }
    }
```

---

```
public abstract class Enumeration : IComparable
    {
        private readonly int _value;
        private readonly string _displayName;

        protected Enumeration()
        {
        }

        protected Enumeration(int value, string displayName)
        {
            _value = value;
            _displayName = displayName;
        }

        public int Value
        {
            get { return _value; }
        }

        public string DisplayName
        {
            get { return _displayName; }
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return DisplayName;
        }

        public static IEnumerable<T> GetAll<T>() where T : Enumeration, new()
        {
            var type = typeof(T);
            var fields = type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);

            foreach (var info in fields)
            {
                var instance = new T();
                var locatedValue = info.GetValue(instance) as T;

                if (locatedValue != null)
                {
                    yield return locatedValue;
                }
            }
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            var otherValue = obj as Enumeration;

            if (otherValue == null)
            {
                return false;
            }

            var typeMatches = GetType().Equals(obj.GetType());
            var valueMatches = _value.Equals(otherValue.Value);

            return typeMatches && valueMatches;
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return _value.GetHashCode();
        }

        public static int AbsoluteDifference(Enumeration firstValue, Enumeration secondValue)
        {
            var absoluteDifference = Math.Abs(firstValue.Value - secondValue.Value);
            return absoluteDifference;
        }

        public static T FromValue<T>(int value) where T : Enumeration, new()
        {
            var matchingItem = parse<T, int>(value, "value", item => item.Value == value);
            return matchingItem;
        }

        public static T FromDisplayName<T>(string displayName) where T : Enumeration, new()
        {
            var matchingItem = parse<T, string>(displayName, "display name", item => item.DisplayName == displayName);
            return matchingItem;
        }

        private static T parse<T, K>(K value, string description, Func<T, bool> predicate) where T : Enumeration, new()
        {
            var matchingItem = GetAll<T>().FirstOrDefault(predicate);

            if (matchingItem == null)
            {
                var message = string.Format("'{0}' is not a valid {1} in {2}", value, description, typeof(T));
                throw new ApplicationException(message);
            }

            return matchingItem;
        }

        public int CompareTo(object other)
        {
            return Value.CompareTo(((Enumeration)other).Value);
        }
    }
```

---

So based on the user selection for a specific option or set of options, I have to call a method to set flags `(IsFixed,...)` in the Schedule class to control the the scheduledetails class in (Fixed and rotated) and the number of hours for(full time and part time)

---

I'll be grateful for any suggestions or recommendations ?

Comment: And why did you create custom class Enumeration instead of using built-in enum?

Comment: @Evk because I want to handle each item in the enum as a specific Type and call a method in it. So I Search how to handle this and found the following article https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2008/08/12/enumeration-classes/

Comment: You question is not clear to me. Can you provide an example of syntax you are after? `Flags` attribute is of no use here by the way, since your type is not enum. If you just want to combine different `ScheduleType`s - add some method and combine as you wish: `var combined = ScheduleType.Fixed.And(ScheduleType.FullTime)`

Comment: Without the bounty this question would get closed as "unclear" or "too broad". It's not clear where your code doesn't meet your requirements (if anywhere) or what kind of suggestions and recommendations you're after. A bounty doesn't make a question answerable.

Comment: @GertArnold  although I ‘ve  explained enough, but I want to enable multiple selections for the items in the class with specific conditions explained in the question. And I ask if this way is the correct path for this problem or there’s a better solution and I tried to solve the problem in the wrong way :)

Comment: @GertArnold Why Downvote :( I tried to explain my problem

Comment: @Evk There will be a dropdown list for schedule types, so the user can select one or more(not conflicted) of these types and according to their selections I'll call functions to handle the different cases

Comment: Not my downvote.

Comment: @GertArnold Could You help me to find a proper solution please

Comment: I think you should use two enums of mutually exclusive values: Fixed/Rotated/Flexible and FullTime/PartTime.

Comment: I don't see anything EF related in this question, so removing the `entity-framework` tag.

Comment: I don’t think down-voting a bounty question without clarifying the reason to allow me to explain more is a great action. Please If you are gonna to downvote a question at least write a comment !!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This following `ScheduleType` example has the ability to hold multiple types similar to how bit fields are used. Note the hex values used for the value of the types that would allow logical operations to determine what types make up the current value.

```
public class ScheduleType : FlagsValueObject<ScheduleType> {
    public static readonly ScheduleType Fixed = new ScheduleType(0x01, "Fixed");
    public static readonly ScheduleType Flexible = new ScheduleType(0x02, "Flexible");
    public static readonly ScheduleType FullTime = new ScheduleType(0x04, "Full Time");
    public static readonly ScheduleType PartTime = new ScheduleType(0x08, "Part Time");
    public static readonly ScheduleType Rotated = new ScheduleType(0x10, "Rotated");

    protected ScheduleType(int value, string name)
        : base(value, name) {
    }

    private ScheduleType(ScheduleType a, ScheduleType b) {
        foreach (var kvp in a.Types.Union(b.Types)) {
            Types[kvp.Key] = kvp.Value;
        }            
        Name = string.Join(", ", Types.OrderBy(kvp => kvp.Value).Select(kvp => kvp.Value)) + " Work Schedule";
        Value = Types.Keys.Sum();
    }

    protected override ScheduleType Or(ScheduleType other) {
        var result = new ScheduleType(this, other);

        //Applying validation rules on new combination
        if (result.HasFlag(Fixed) && result.HasFlag(Rotated))
            throw new InvalidOperationException("ScheduleType cannot be both Fixed and Rotated");

        if (result.HasFlag(FullTime) && result.HasFlag(PartTime))
            throw new InvalidOperationException("ScheduleType cannot be both FullTime and PartTime");

        return result;
    }
}
```

Using the `HasFlag` to determine what combination exists within the flag, the desired business rules can be applied.

for example

```
//Applying validation rules on new combination
if (result.HasFlag(Fixed) && result.HasFlag(Rotated))
    throw new InvalidOperationException("ScheduleType cannot be both Fixed and Rotated");

if (result.HasFlag(FullTime) && result.HasFlag(PartTime))
    throw new InvalidOperationException("ScheduleType cannot be both FullTime and PartTime");
```

The rules were applied when combining flags to prevent the creation of any unwanted combinations.

It is derived from the following supporting value objects

*FlagsValueObject*

```
public abstract class FlagsValueObject<T> : EnumValueObject where T : FlagsValueObject<T> {
    protected readonly IDictionary<int, string> Types = new SortedDictionary<int, string>();

    protected FlagsValueObject(int value, string name)
        : base(value, name) {
        Types[value] = name;
    }

    protected FlagsValueObject() {

    }

    public static T operator |(FlagsValueObject<T> left, T right) {
        return left.Or(right);
    }

    protected abstract T Or(T other);

    public virtual bool HasFlag(T flag) {
        return flag != null && (Value & flag.Value) == flag.Value;
    }

    public virtual bool HasFlagValue(int value) {
        return (Value & value) == value;
    }
}
```

*EnumValueObject*

```
public class EnumValueObject : IEquatable<EnumValueObject>, IComparable<EnumValueObject> {

    protected EnumValueObject(int value, string name) {
        Value = value;
        Name = name;
    }

    protected EnumValueObject() {

    }

    public virtual string Name { get; protected set; }

    public virtual int Value { get; protected set; }

    public static bool operator ==(EnumValueObject left, EnumValueObject right) {
        return Equals(left, right);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(EnumValueObject left, EnumValueObject right) {
        return !Equals(left, right);
    }

    public int CompareTo(EnumValueObject other) {
        return Value.CompareTo(other.Value);
    }

    public bool Equals(EnumValueObject other) {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, other)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, other)) return true;
        return Value.Equals(other.Value);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj) {
        return obj is EnumValueObject && Equals((EnumValueObject)obj);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode() {
        return Value.GetHashCode();
    }

    public override string ToString() {
        return Name;
    }
}
```

Simple example unit test.

```
[TestClass]
public class ScheduleTypeValueObjectTests {
    [TestMethod]
    public void Should_Merge_Names() {
        //Arrange
        var fixedSchedult = ScheduleType.Fixed; //Fixed Work Schedule
        var fullTime = ScheduleType.FullTime; // Full Time Work Schedule
        var type = fixedSchedult | fullTime;

        //Act
        var actual = type.Name;

        //Assert
        actual.Should().Be("Fixed, Full Time Work Schedule");
    }


    [TestMethod]
    [ExpectedException(typeof(InvalidOperationException))]
    public void Should_Fail_Bitwise_Combination() {
        //Arrange
        var fullTime = ScheduleType.FullTime; // Full Time Work Schedule
        var partTime = ScheduleType.PartTime;

        var value = fullTime | partTime;
    }
}
```

The `HasFlag` property allows the ability to check what types exist within the flag as demonstrated in the following example.

```
public class Schedule {
    public Schedule(
        //...
        ScheduleType scheduleType
        //...
        ) {

        //...

        ScheduleType = scheduleType;
    }

    //...

    public ScheduleType ScheduleType { get; set; }
    public bool IsFixed {
        get {
            return ScheduleType != null && ScheduleType.HasFlag(ScheduleType.Fixed);
        }
    }
    public bool IsFlexible {
        get {
            return
                ScheduleType != null && ScheduleType.HasFlag(ScheduleType.Flexible);
        }
    }
    public bool IsFullTime {
        get {
            return
                ScheduleType != null && ScheduleType.HasFlag(ScheduleType.FullTime);
        }
    }

    //...
}
```

Comment: Could I create the following method in my `ScheduleType` class to set the flags and call that method in the `Schedule constructor` .

Comment: `public Tuple<bool, bool, bool> VerifyScheduleTypes()
        {bool isFixed = false;bool isFlexible = false;bool isFullTime = false;
            if (this == Fixed)
            { isFixed = true;}
            else if (this == Rotated)
            { isFixed = false;}

            if (this == FullTime)
            { isFullTime = true; }
            else if (this == PartTime)
            {isFullTime = false; }
            if (this == Flexible)
            {isFlexible = true; }
            return Tuple.Create(isFixed, isFullTime, isFlexible);
        }`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort, I'm really grateful. Could you explain How to update my previous method to allow different combinations ?

Comment: @AnynameDonotcare I an not clear on what it is you want done from your recent comments. Where would that logic live?

Comment: this method should be in the `ScheduleType` class and according to the user selection I want to set the flags in the `Schedule` class constructor so that the details will varies based on that.

Comment: `public Schedule(string name, int workingGroupId, ScheduleType scheduleType)
        {Name = name;WorkingGroupId = workingGroupId;
            ScheduleType = scheduleType;
            Tuple<bool, bool, bool> scheduleVerification = scheduleType.VerifyScheduleTypes();
            IsFixed = scheduleVerification.Item1;
            IsFullTime = scheduleVerification.Item2;
            IsFlexible = scheduleVerification.Item3;
            AssignedWeeks = new List<ScheduleDetail>();
            EnrolledParties = new List<ScheduleEnrolment>();
        }`

Comment: @AnynameDonotcare I believe that logic should live in the `Schedule` class, and the same functionality achieved withing the property ie `public bool IsFixed { get { return this.ScheduleType.HasFlag(ScheduleType.Fixed); } }` The same can be done for the other properties

Comment: Thanks a lot, This's more simpler, I felt I made things more complex :(
Should I put it in the `Schedule` constructor ?

Comment: there is no need for it in the constructor if it is being done in the property. Once type is set in constructor those other properties will get their values as a result. `public bool IsFixed { get { return this.ScheduleType != null && this.ScheduleType.HasFlag(ScheduleType.Fixed); } }`

Comment: @AnynameDonotcare after some consultation, it was determined that rules related to conflicted combinations can be applied within the value object. Check the latest update.

Comment: Could I ask how we could set `FixedANDFulltime` as the default Schedule type ?

Comment: @AnynameDonotcare sure, just for clarification, are you referring to setting it on the `Schedule` class?

Comment: I mean, How to set this default in the `ScheduleType` because I thought it's n't a good idea to set this in the Schedule constructor

Comment: @AnynameDonotcare hmmm, sounds a little tricky. Each instance is created as a single type and then can be combined. I'm thinking you could add something like `public const ScheduleType Default = Fixed | FullTime;` and use that if the value provided in the constructor is null. What do you think?

Comment: Very  good :D, I'm sorry If ask many questions but I have the last question. Is it allowed here to combine more than two types I mean I could select `Fixed|FullTime|Flexible`

Comment: @AnynameDonotcare yes you can combine. You control what can be combined. The value object gives you that flexibility, Just like how in the `Or` method you can check to make sure certain combinations are not done but any amount can be combined once they do not break the custom rules set by the value object.

Comment: BTW: I think I should  use `public readonly static ScheduleType Default = ScheduleType.Fixed | ScheduleType.FullTime;` Instead of `const` Am I right ?

Comment: @AnynameDonotcare I chose `const` to differentiate it from the other types but I see no other reason why you can't do that.

Answer (score 10):

You're overcomplicating this too much. The first issue I suspect is you (or your business analyst) don't have enough grasp on the busines subject - i.e. *shift*. What you have here are two, different enumerations:

```
public enum ScheduleType 
{
    Unknown = 0,
    Fixed,
    Rotated
}

public enum ScheduleLoad 
{
    Unknown = 0,
    FullTime,
    PartTime
}
```

Next, in the UI you need two different dropdown boxes / radio groups to allow the user to arrange the shift layout, then save this in two different properties of your object.

However, if you insist on having this in one enumeration, thus one propery with flagged enum values, you need to *validate* the user input before saving the flags to you store.

```
[Flags]
public enum ShiftLayout
{
    Unknown = 0,
    Fixed = 1,
    Rotated = 2,
    FullTime = 4,
    PartTime = 8,
    Flexible = 16
}
```

Then the validation is performed like this:

```
public bool IsShiftLayoutValid(ShiftLayout layout)
{
    var isValid = layout.HasFlag(ShiftLayout.Flexible) 
        && (layout & ~ShiftLayout.Flexible) == ShiftLayout.Unknown;

    if (!isValid && !layout.HasFlag(ShiftLayout.Flexible))
    {
        var hasValidSchedule = (layout.HasFlag(ShiftLayout.Fixed) && !layout.HasFlag(ShiftLayout.Rotated))
            || layout.HasFlag(ShiftLayout.Rotated);

        var hasValidTime = (layout.HasFlag(ShiftLayout.FullTime) && !layout.HasFlag(ShiftLayout.PartTime))
            || layout.HasFlag(ShiftLayout.PartTime);

        isValid = hasValidSchedule && hasValidTime;
    }

    return isValid;
}
```

Comment: I think main problem is OP tries to "follow DDD" and for that reason wants to use classes instead of simple enums (to incorporate business logic in them).

Answer (score 4):

Just use 2 enums.

1 for Work type (fixed etc)
and 1 for work load (full time etc)

then a bool for flexible.

Do not complicate things for no reason, as, looking at what you did, you put up a lot of unnecessary code to do a comparison.

If you really want to keep everything in one enum, you will save so much more code by doing an enum like

- Fixed
- FixedFullTime
- FixedPartTime
- Rotated
- RotatedFullTime
- RotatedPartTime

etc etc etc with all the combinations.

You have a low number of enum combinations and it's not worth doing custom code to check all the combinations with an IComparable

Just use different enums and in your schedule class those

```
public bool IsFixed { get; }
public bool IsFlexible { get; }
public bool IsFullTime { get; }
```

with a comparison between Fixed/Rotated, Fulltime/Parttime etc etc

or use only a single enum.

Answer (score 4):

As I said in my first answer - this is too complicated. But achievable.

When I re-read the post title I realized that you might want to apply the logical operations to the class, used instead of a standard C# `enum`. For that matter, one needs to implement the operators themselves. So I played a bit to get my hands dirty and voila...

First, define the dummy `Enumeration` class.

```
public abstract class Enumeration
{

    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual string Description { get; protected set; }

}
```

Note that I've dropped most of the methods from your implementation. Some (`Equals`, `GetAll`) are removed for brevity, but others (`FromValue<T>`) have improved implementation later; keep reading ...

```
public partial class ShiftVariant : Enumeration
{
    #region Variations' classes

    private class FixedShiftVariation : ShiftVariant
    {
        public FixedShiftVariation()
        {
            Id = FixedShiftId;
            Description = "Fixed Shift";
        }
    }

    private class RotatedShiftVariant : ShiftVariant
    {
        public RotatedShiftVariant()
        {
            Id = RotatedShiftId;
            Description = "Rotated Shift";
        }
    }

    private class FullTimeShiftVariation : ShiftVariant
    {
        public FullTimeShiftVariation()
        {
            Id = FullTimeShiftId;
            Description = "Full-time Shift";
        }
    }

    private class PartTimeShiftVariation : ShiftVariant
    {
        public PartTimeShiftVariation()
        {
            Id = PartTimeShiftId;
            Description = "Part-time Shift";
        }
    }

    private class FlexibleShiftVariation : ShiftVariant
    {
        public FlexibleShiftVariation()
        {
            Id = FlexibleShiftId;
            Description = "Flexible Shift";
        }
    }

    #endregion

    protected static int FixedShiftId = 2;
    protected static int RotatedShiftId = 4;
    protected static int FullTimeShiftId = 8;
    protected static int PartTimeShiftId = 16;
    protected static int FlexibleShiftId = 32;

    public static ShiftVariant NotSet = new ShiftVariant() { Id = 0, Description = "Unknown" };

    public static ShiftVariant FixedShift = new FixedShiftVariation();

    public static ShiftVariant RotatedShift = new RotatedShiftVariant();

    public static ShiftVariant FullTimeShift = new FullTimeShiftVariation();

    public static ShiftVariant PartTimeShift = new PartTimeShiftVariation();

    public static ShiftVariant FlexibleShift = new FlexibleShiftVariation();

    private static Dictionary<int, ShiftVariant> AllTheVariations = new Dictionary<int, ShiftVariant>
    {
        { FixedShiftId, FixedShift },
        { RotatedShiftId, RotatedShift },
        { FullTimeShiftId, FullTimeShift },
        { PartTimeShiftId, PartTimeShift },
        { FlexibleShiftId, FlexibleShift }
    };

    /// <summary>
    /// Enable initialization off of an integer.
    /// This replaces your FromValue<T> method. You can repeat it for strings too, matching the descriptions.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="id"></param>
    public static implicit operator ShiftVariant(int id)
    {
        return AllTheVariations.ContainsKey(id) ? AllTheVariations[id] : new ShiftVariant { Id = id };
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Enable binary OR
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="left"></param>
    /// <param name="right"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static ShiftVariant operator |(ShiftVariant left, ShiftVariant right)
    {
        return new ShiftVariant
        {
            Id = left.Id | right.Id,
        };
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Enable binary AND
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="left"></param>
    /// <param name="right"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static ShiftVariant operator &(ShiftVariant left, ShiftVariant right)
    {
        return new ShiftVariant
        {
            Id = left.Id & right.Id
        };
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Enable COMPLEMENT ONE'S (negation)
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="left"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static ShiftVariant operator ~(ShiftVariant left)
    {
        return new ShiftVariant
        {
            Id = ~left.Id
        };
    }

    private string CalculatedDesc = null;

    public override string Description
    {
        get => CalculatedDesc ?? CalculateDescription();
        protected set => CalculatedDesc = value;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Description;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Figure out the description by walking currently set flags
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private string CalculateDescription()
    {
        CalculatedDesc = string.Empty;

        if (AllTheVariations.ContainsKey(Id))
        {
            CalculatedDesc = AllTheVariations[Id].Description;
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var variation in AllTheVariations)
            {
                if ((Id & variation.Key) == variation.Key)
                {
                    CalculatedDesc += " | " + variation.Value.Description;
                }
            }

            CalculatedDesc = CalculatedDesc.TrimStart(" |".ToCharArray());
        }

        return CalculatedDesc;
    }
}
```

The main class - `ShiftVariant` - is declared private so at a later point (perhaps in another assembly) you can extend it with new *enumerations* like so:

```
public class ShiftVariant
{
    private class SomeOtherShiftVariation : ShiftVariation
    {
        // ...
    }

    protected static int SomeOtherShiftId = 64;

    public static ShiftVariation SomeShift = new SomeOtherShiftVariation();

    // add the new shift variation to AllTheVariations dictonary

}
```

Answer (score 3):

I would use 1 enumerator type and annotate them as flags, you this by placings [Flags] on top of the enumerator.

You can then make read-only properties or declare them in the enum. that contain groups of any of the flags making those flags valid for that choice. This way you would not only have valid options but you can re-use this in a database by checking if a flag is in bit-wise group. just as you could in your code.

Here is what I think is a simple one that all can relate to:

```
[Flags]
public enum Role
{
    None=0
    NormalUser = 1,
    Moderator  = 2,
    Accounting = 4,
    Membership = 8,
    Blocked    = 16
    BackOffice = Membership | Accounting | Moderator  
    Admin      = NormalUser | Moderator  | Membership 
}
```

You can store all in a property of Type Role.
You can be a BackOffice role and be blocked, you test this in c#
using a bitwise compare

```
if(testRole & Role.Blocked == Role.Blocked)
{
   return;//blocked user
}
```

Here is [a nice article](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1218/sql-server-bitwise-operators-store-multiple-values-in-one-column/) about bitwise testing in TSQL, bitwise operations are fast and available in all databases i think

Answer (score 3):

Flags Attribute is generally used when you have lists of elements with combinations. You use it with Bitwise operations only. You can find the full details here.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute(v=vs.110).aspx